# Why do non-parametric test works?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, references, nonparametric

I found a lecture notes about non-parametric statistics. I studied those on my own so that I can use them. But I had difficulties to understand why do we do some test as we do. So is there a lecture notes or books or papers where I can study why those methods makes sense?

I'm a mathematician so I can read better texts where everything has been proven.

Comment: As far as lecture notes, I can recommend this [nonparametrics course](http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/5601/) from UMN. It has quite a few notes and examples available, and, even though the class isn't especially math-y, it definitely has an eye toward theory.

Answer (score 2):

I like [this paper](http://www.aspbooks.org/a/volumes/article_details/?paper_id=3332) because it has enough details to understand the math behind, but it is also with applications: Astrostatistics: Goodness-of-Fit and All That! by Babu, G.J.; Feigelson, E.D. You can jump right into Section 4 if Astrphysics is not your thing :)